# Shell Script: error during comparison (Linux)

Tags: linux, shell, makefile

I am passing an argument into a shell script through make using:

```
smktestrun: smktest
        @../projects/test.sh $(TESTARGS)
```

Then call the Makefile with

```
$ make smktestrun TESTARGS="-abc"
```

And my code inside the shell script is:

```
if [ "$1" == "-abc" ]; then
    ./test123
else
    ./test678
fi
```

But I get the following error:

```
+ [ -abc == -abc ]
15:15:08 [: 1: -abc: unexpected operator
```

And so the else part of the code gets executed. 
I also tried  `if [ "$1" -eq "-abc" ];`
but that also gave a similar error.

Could someone please help me figure out what is going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: At a guess I'd say you're trying to execute that script with the wrong kind of shell. What OS are you using?

Comment: have you tried "if [ "$S1" = "-abc" ];" AFAIK you're using arithmetic comparison operator, not a String comparison operator, and "-abc" is String.

Comment: Set TESTARGS to -def. What's the output then?

Comment: @hovanessyan Bash works with = as well with ==, tho with [ ] it's not posix compliant. But does he use bash at all?

Comment: no idea what he uses, though different things can work in different environments, documentation clearly states which comparison operator to be used for Strings and for Numbers (ref: tlpd.org)

Comment: appears to be dash.  running `if [ "-abc" == "-abc" ]; then echo yay; else echo nay; fi` in dash results in `[: 1: -abc: unexpected operator`.

Answer (score 2):

The correct operator is `=`, not `==` or `-eq`:

```
if [ "$1" = "-abc" ]; then
    ./test123
else
    ./test678
fi
```

Comment: To expand on this, `==` works in *some* cases, `=` is for string comparison, and `-eq` is for number comparison.

Comment: This does not explain why a similar error is given when `-eq` is used instead of `==`.

Comment: When -eq is used, the errors you get are (on bash and dash): `test: -abc: integer expression expected` and `test: 1: Illegal number: -abc`. Both errors are complainging that `-abc` is not a number.

Comment: `-eq` compares two expressions, whereas `=` compares two strings.  OP appears to be using dash, which does not implement `==`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like somehow you are using an invalid implementation of `[`.  Whether it is a builtin to the shell that make is invoking, or `/usr/bin/[`.  As a workaround, you can probably do:

```
if test x"$1" = x"-abc"; then
```

Note that using `==` as an operator to `test` is not portable.   Use `=` instead.

Comment: That `x"$1"` is for MSDOS et al. `if test "-abc" = "-def" ; then echo equal ; else echo not ; fi` works very well.

Comment: The `x"$1"` is a common technique on older shells which implemented `[` poorly.